# Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved. Error while trying to connect to CRM Online 2015

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

**Background:** I am using a Windows Service to connect to CRM Online 2015 to get specific data from there and move it to a local SQL database for reporting purposes.

This is a well tested code that was running on the server of our client. Recently the service stopped and when i debugged it i got the following error. 
[image]

This is otherwise working on my local machine but not on the server the service was originally installed on. What could be the reason for this? The client says that there is no firewall on the server. 
Could it be the domain credentials I am using?

Here is the piece of code I am using to connect to CRM [image]

I get an error at

```
OrganizationServiceProxy serviceProxy=newOrganizationServiceProxy(OrganizationUri, null, credentials, null);
```

NOTE: When I try to open any website or even crm instance itself the browser shows me the following:

[image]

Any Help guys?

Comment: The 2nd screenshot contains the answer for your question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your client installed a new set of rules on his SonicWALL or even started to use a SonicWALL. If I see it right the SonicWALL blocks your request.

Comment: Even though the client says that there is no firewall on the server?

Comment: The Screenshot you posted shows that something was blocked. You could try to trace the route and look where the Firewall might be.

Comment: would Fiddler help in that?

Comment: i will try to convince the client

Answer (score 1):

SonicWall is a router, Network Administration may have blocked this category in router.